# Pulling PHP data into JS to dynamically change BG image on screen width

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my WP Template I created two ***Sub fields*** in my ***Repeater*** custom fields for bg imgs:

1. The large device and desktop bg
2. The mobile bg

In my `content-section.php` template part, I created a loop and inject `get_sub_field('background_image');` as a bg image successfully. I'd like to dynamically change the bg-img to mobile when the width is `< 768`. I know you have to pass the php data over to js by using `wp_localize_script()` etc..

**What I've tried:**

1. Set a var for `get_sub_field('mobile_background_image');` in `content-section.php`
2. Used different variation of AFC Functions to pull bg data in `functions.php`: `the_field('mobile_background_image')`, `get_sub_field('mobile_background_image')`, `the_sub_field('mobile_background_image');` but don't even see any data pulled when I `console.log()` the var, the most I get is null
3. Wrote my `.each()` multiple ways:

   ```
   // Attempt #1
   $('.bg-img').each(function() {

     if($(window).width() < 768) {
       var bgUrl = 'url("' + php_vars.mobile_bg + '") center center no-repeat)'
       var style = {
           'background': bgUrl,
           'background-size': 'cover'
       }
       $('.bg-img').css(style);
     }

   }); 

   // Attempt #2
   if($(window).width() < 768) {

     $('.bg-img').each(function() {
       var bgUrl = 'url("' + php_vars.mobile_bg + '") center center no-repeat)'
       var style = {
           'background': bgUrl,
           'background-size': 'cover'
       }

       $('.bg-img').css(style);
     });   

   }
   ```

Also variations where `$('.bg-img').css(style);` was completely outside the function.

**Question(s):** For some reason I am not seeing any change when I inspect nor any console errors. How can I properly pull the ***sub_field*** data and pass that to and from my functions.php to my scripts.js and once that data is pulled and set in a var is my current function using `.each() if();` etc... correct?

**Content-section.php**

```
<?php if( have_rows('section_content') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('section_content') ): the_row(); 
        $sectionBG = get_sub_field('background_image');
        $sectionContent = get_sub_field('section_text');
    ?>
        <?php if( $sectionBG ): ?>
            <div style="background: url('<?php echo $sectionBG ?>') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;" class="full-height v-center-content bg-img">
        <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="container animation-element">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php if(get_row_index() % 2 == 0) : ?>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-xl-5 offset-xl-7">
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-5">
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                            <div class="section-content">
                                <?php echo $sectionContent ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php if( $sectionBG ): ?>  
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Function.php**

```
wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

wp_localize_script('main-js', 'php_vars', array(
    'mobile_bg' =>  get_sub_field('mobile_background_image')
));
}
```

**Script.js**

```
$('.bg-img').each(function() {

    if($(window).width() < 768) {

        var bgUrl = 'url("' + php_vars.mobile_bg + '") center center no-repeat)'
        var style = {
            'background': bgUrl,
            'background-size': 'cover'
        }

        $('.bg-img').css(style);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tinkering I have found a solution that allows me to dynamically pull in the ACF data within a repeater field from my functions php and use in my script.js

The issue was that I was trying to pull the `get_sub_field()` data without running the `has_rows` loop, hence why I was receiving no data.

**Updated functions.php**

```
$php_vars = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'root_dir'  =>  get_template_directory_uri()
);

if (have_rows('section_content')) :
    while (have_rows('section_content')) : the_row();

        $mobile_url[] = get_sub_field('mobile_background_image');

        $php_vars['mobile_bg'] = $mobile_url;
    endwhile;
endif;

print_r($php_vars);

wp_localize_script('main-js', 'php_vars', $php_vars);
```

Within my `functions.php` I created a `have_loop`- [more info here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) - to check if I have the repeater field on the page, if so, set the mobile image url(s) as an array. After that, I create a multidimensional array and add that to my `$php_vars`.

---

**Updated script.js**

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {

    var bgIMG = php_vars.mobile_bg;
    var i;

    console.log(bgIMG);

    for ( i = 0; i < bgIMG.length; i++) {
        $('.bg-img').attr('style', 'background: url("'+ bgIMG[i] +'") center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;');
    }

}
```

After successfully testing that the url(s) were being stored as an array via `print_r($php_vars);` I'm able to called that data into my script and storing it into a var `bgIMG`. Testing to see if the data is still intact using `console.log(bgIMG)`, I create a for loop to to add the data into my background url and increment.

---

This is the solution I figured out that seems to work. If anyone has a better solution or advice on how to improve this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

This is the role of CSS media queries.
In your main style sheet you would have

```
background-image: url('pic1.jpg');
```

In your mobile css file you would have

```
background-image: url('pic2.jpg');
```

In your html you would have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='mobile.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:768px)">
```

Comment: I understand that it is the role of css media query. Maybe my question is unclear? Unless there is a way I can pull the advanced custom field php data `get_sub_field('mobile_background_image')` and inject that into the media query css, I don't see this working. It needs to be dynamic due to the fact that this is a template and the image is subject to change at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
   if($(this).width() < 768)
   {
     ('.bg-img').each(function() {
        var bgUrl = 'url("' + php_vars.mobile_bg + '") center center no-repeat)'
        var style = {'background': bgUrl,
                     'background-size': 'cover'};
        $(this).css(style);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: That is a hard coded solution, I am looking for a dynamic solution. Because I am using wordpress, I need to pull the data from the custom field and replace the set data with the new data in the loop.

Comment: Please try the code. If it was a problem, let me know. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This question might be old - but you can just install the mobble plugin - this tells you what kind of device in on you page - it also adds a class for the body.

Then you can simply use the plugins core functions -

```
<?php
//is_handheld(); // any handheld device (phone, tablet, Nintendo)
//is_mobile(); // any type of mobile phone (iPhone, Android, etc)
//is_tablet(); // any tablet device
//is_ios(); // any Apple device (iPhone, iPad, iPod)
/*is_iphone();
//is_ipad();
//is_ipod();
//is_android();
//is_blackberry();
//is_opera_mobile();
//is_symbian();
//is_kindle();
//is_windows_mobile();
//is_motorola();
//is_samsung();
//is_samsung_tablet();
//is_sony_ericsson();
//is_nintendo(); */

if(is_mobile()) {
    $bgURL = get_sub_field("your mobile image here"); 
} else {
    $bgURL = get_sub_field("your desktop image here");
}
```

Read more about the plugins functions and download here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobble/

Comment: Also - I realize that this isn't "pulling data into JS" - but it gets the job done and bypasses the need for it.